# Custom Components in WindowBuilder

Tags: java, windowbuilder

I am trying to make my own Java component for use with windowBuilder in eclipse. Creating the component is the easy part. The problem is getting eclipse to draw the component when one is created.
I have tried using SWT designer but that doesn't exactly work (can't make completely custom components).

Example:
If I want to create a Line component, which has 2 point members, I can't set the points from the design view of eclipse. 
I was wondering whether this can be done.

I realize this might sound vague, and I will make any clarifications needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preview use:

[image]

It should also be possible to add custom component to WindowBuilder:
right-click on the swing palette, then choose Palette manager .

[image]

You'll have the option to import a jar file to be added to the palette.

I am not familiar with an option to make a custom component visible in the static WindowBuilder view.

Comment: the problem with that is that the new component doesn't get drawn on the JFrame in the design view